# Effective multiple return values

Tags: c, function, return, multiple-variable-return

Lets imagine that we have function that should return two return values.
For instance we have some function that returns `char*` and its length. Char is allocated within that particular function.

I can imagine following ways of doing that:

```
int foo(char **result);       // Passing pointer to char*, returning int
char* bar(int *len);          // Passing pointer to int, returning char*
struct char_and_len foobar(); // Returning struct that contains both values
```

Is there any other ways to implement multiple values and what's the most effective way to do that?

I'd really appreciate detailed explanation, considering performance, memory alignment or any other hidden C feature.

Comment: Why get any more clever than the options you've provided? You'll only be obfuscating your code by doing so.

Comment: @meagar. Why? I'm curious what's the other ways of doing that. There might be some really interesting reasons of doing that. Moreover, I have strong feeling that in C different ways of doing the same thing might have different effects and considerations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two cases here. If you are working in a codebase/framework (e.g. Glib) that has a standard string struct used throughout *the entire application*, then use your third option:

```
struct string function();
```

If your codebase is not using one standard struct everywhere for strings, I would advise against using a struct. The hassle of converting back and forth is not really worth it.

Otherwise, the convention (at least that I've seen) is to return the `char*` and have the length as a pointer parameter:

```
char* function(int* length);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate why `char* f(int*)` vs `int f(char **)`

Comment: @Sigurd: At least in most of the code and library functions I've seen, `char**` is used when the caller is responsible for memory allocation and has already determined the length, or is providing a maximum length. For example, in the Linux system call `read(2)`, you provide a preallocated buffer and a maximum data length for that buffer.

Comment: "Otherwise, the convention is to return the char* and have the length as a pointer parameter:" -- asserting that the convention **is** this is a tad bit harsh. There are other, equally valid conventions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
void foo(char **result, int *len);
```

The worst in my opinion is:

```
struct char_and_len foobar();
```

The one I prefer is the one I showed you, because I don't like to mix return values in both arguments and effective return.

Answer (score 1):

You can just return an array and wrap it in a struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char *strings[2];
} RetType;

RetType func()
{
    return (RetType){ { "foo", "bar" } };
}
```

Another idiomatic solution is C to pass an array to your function and have it filled:

```
void func(char *strings[2])
{
    strings[0] = "foo";
    strings[1] = "bar";
}
```

A third solution is to return one value and pass the other one by pointer (though this is more meaningful if you have values of distinct types):

```
char *func(char **outparm)
{
    *outparm = "foo";
    return "bar";
}
```

Also, excuse me for not being `const`-correct.

Comment: I might be not too clear in my question. I need to return int and char *. Let's imagine that char is not terminated with \0 so we do have to return its length.

Comment: @Sigurd Then you can change your `struct` to contain a `char *` and an `int`. And you can change one of the return values in the third example to an `int` too. And forget about the second approach.

Comment: I know how to return multiple values :) My question was what's the most effective way and why.

Comment: @Sigurd Effective in what sense? I've listed all the practically possible solutions. Pick one. It really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite would be

```
void foobar(struct char_and_len*);
```

For the following reasons:

- Only a single parameter needs to be passed
- return value / out parameter aren't mixed
- return values can be ignored, especially when the return value needs to be deallocated again this can be a serious source of programming errors. Out parameters cannot be ignored.
- Having a pointer to the struct avoids too much copy operations. Only one pointer needs to be provided to the function.
- This way the caller of the function can decide where the `struct char_and_len` is stored (on the heap, stack) while when using return values the data needs to be put on the stack at least temporarily

Comment: If you have a struct made for this purpose why not return the whole struct by value.

Comment: While in general I would agree with you, because we're dealing with strings here don't you think it's a problem to be defining a string "type" that has to be converted to and from?

Answer (score 1):

**Use a string.**

For the specific example you cite, remember that length is implicitly or explicitly a property of any string type. For example, C-style strings are null-terminated, so even though there's not an explicit length the caller can still determine the length of the string. Pascal-style strings include length as the first byte. `char*` isn't necessarily a string, it might be a plain old text buffer where you *do* need the length. But the point of string types is to avoid the need to pass data and length separately.

**More generally...**

A function can only *return* one value, so if you need to return more than that you need to either package everything up into a single value using a struct, or pass a pointer (or pointers) to a location to receive the results. Which method you use depends on the circumstances. Do you already have a struct defined for the data that needs to be returned? Is the caller likely to have an existing object that could receive the results? There is no *best* method, only an *appropriate* method for the situation.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is always work with pointers. In C, every function duplicate the arguments passed in a different zone of memory. The best way is the second one of the three that you have posted in term of performance.

But I would pass as argument a pointer to a struct wich contains both, lenght and string with a void return.

Comment: Strings in C are always pointers, no matter whether you pass the pointer itself by reference or value.

Comment: Yep, but he has an int too.

Comment: An int is typically four bytes. On a 32-bit system, so is a pointer. On a 64-bit system, the pointer (8 bytes) will actually be *larger* than the `int`.

Comment: On a 64-bit system int and *int have the same size, 4 bytes not 8. I have just checked that (On 32-bit system it is 2 bytes). So in that case you are not going to notice any improvement on performance :P

For that reason I said that I would use a single pointer to a struct with both data type in it.

Answer (score 0):

In C it isn't "normal" to return two values. That means that as you already did you could create a struct to return the result. That is the formally correct way of doing it, but not the simplest one and it is coumbersome. So I would totaly forget that solution.

Generically, the other way of returning results is by passing arguments by reference (in Pascal VB etc ).
In C there is not the possibility to pass them by reference instead a pointer is passed.
But in C++ there is the possibility to pass the variable by reference ( that simply means passing the pointer but using the variable ).

So I believe the simplest way of doing what you need is to define:

char* bar(int *lenP);          //

now you have the result of a function that could return two results:

like if it was defined as pseudo syntax (s,l)=bar();

Additionally you could also use:

void bar(char  * *s,int * lenP); // that case treats equally the too arguments.

In C++ I would use the by reference approach because while being the same from the practical point of view  (what the processor does) it is simpler for the programmer.